# Lodash: replace value in array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, lodash

To replace value in array of objects, and in this case the `created_at` with 'jan', 'Feb' etc, I can certainly use map through as shown below.

But is there a shorter way using lodash?

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import _ from 'lodash'
import moment from 'moment'

interface DataProps {
  clazz_name: string
  created_at: string
}

const dataone: DataProps[] = [
  {
    clazz_name: '1A',
    created_at: '2022-01-19T09:13:42.149+08:00',
  },
  {
    clazz_name: '1B',
    created_at: '2022-02-19T09:13:42.149+08:00',
  },
]

let datatwo: DataProps[] = []

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    dataone.forEach((item) =>
      datatwo.push({
        clazz_name: item.clazz_name,
        created_at: moment(item.created_at).format('MMM'),
      })
    )
    console.log(datatwo)
  }, [])

  return <div>Test</div>
}

export default App
```

Any hint or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's [misusing `map`](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/04/17/misusing-map/) (post on my blog). If you're not returning something in the `map` callback and using the array `map` creates, just use a loop (or `forEach`, which is a loop of function calls).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, yes there was a warning about not returning something.

Comment: It's also quite odd to have a component that pushes elements into an array held outside the component like that. Why do it there and not where you create `datatwo`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, these are all test code just to know how it can be replaced by lodash.  I might make mistakes somewhere but no worry about it for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `_.map` like below

```
const dataTwo = _.map(dataOne, item => ({...item, created_at: moment(item.created_at).format('MMM') }))
```

Comment: That doesn't do the same thing the OP's code does. The OP's code **adds** to `datatwo` when `App` is mounted. This code fills in `datatwo` immediately. (That would probably be better, which is [why I asked the OP about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71369660/lodash-replace-value-in-array-of-objects?noredirect=1#comment126150459_71369660), but for now they haven't come back with an answer.) There's no reason to use `_.map` in 2022; just use the native `map`. (Granted the OP said "with lodash" but that's likely a red herring.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I realised that I do not need a datatwo here, just use dataone will do.